# PHP curl post request with parameters

Tags: php, curl, post, parameters

I am trying to create a new user subscription using curl, but it seems the parameters never gets sent:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/user_sub/new';

$curl = curl_init($url);

$curl_post_data = array(
    'email' => 'user_email@example.com',
    'f_name' => 'John',
    'l_name' => 'Doe',
    'zip_code' => 'GB211',
    'promo' => 'promocode'
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curl_post_data));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

...

If I do a straight url post over browser it works e.g:

```
http://www.domain.com/user_sub/new?email=user_email@example.com&f_name=John&l_name=Doe&zip_code=GB211&promo=promocode
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: if you use: `/user_sub/new?email=user_email@example.com&f_name=John&l..`  in `/user_sub/new` change $_POST with $_GET

Comment: I don't have access to the database and I'm able to get form entries which will populate the array. The url above is supposed to post to a remote system which I have no control over, hence curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried doing it with:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/user_sub/new?email=user_email@example.com&f_name=John&l_name=Doe&zip_code=GB211&promo=promocode';

        $response = file_get_contents($url, false);
```